# Topography and flash flooding

Tags: meteorology, sea-level, tides, flooding, topography

I'm looking for a study or document  showing the effect of the topography, slopes, the sea level and the tide on flash flooding occurrence.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sea level & tides are irrelevant to flash floods in inland areas. High rainfall in a short time span, topography & vegetation are the main factors